# Create a model change shape in XNA 3D

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I want to create an object that moves (like people are moving or elastic springs), when moving, the shape of the object will be changed. And I do not know how to create a 3D model shape changes in XNA 4.0. Can you help me?? Thanks!

Comment: Well, do you know how to make a 3D model in XNA?

Comment: Yes, I do. I create model 3D by Blender, but I just started learning it.

Comment: Ok, you don't know how to make a model by code. My advice would be, start by trying to make a plane or a cube, completely by code to fully understand how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be able to give you some beginner-to-beginner advice.

I just learned how to make a model from [this example](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/simple_animation) and based on your quesiton I applied an additional scale transform to one of the bones to see if I could manipulate its size the same way I can its position, and it did work.

So I'm implying the answer to your question may be that while a model's vertex data remains constant you can make it change shape using Scale transforms.

Here's my model:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace SimpleAnimation
{
    public class Body
    {
        Model bodyModel;
        ModelBone headBone;
        ModelBone bodyBone;
        Matrix headTransform;
        Matrix bodyTransform;
        Matrix[] boneTransforms;

        public Body()
        {
            HeadScale = 1;
        }

        public void Load(ContentManager content)
        {
            // Load the tank model from the ContentManager.
            bodyModel = content.Load<Model>("body");

            // Look up shortcut references to the bones we are going to animate.
            headBone = bodyModel.Bones["head"];
            bodyBone = bodyModel.Bones["body"];

            // Store the original transform matrix for each animating bone.
            headTransform = headBone.Transform;
            bodyTransform = bodyBone.Transform;

            // Allocate the transform matrix array.
            boneTransforms = new Matrix[bodyModel.Bones.Count];
        }

        public void Draw(Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
        {
            // Set the world matrix as the root transform of the model.
            bodyModel.Root.Transform = world;

            // Calculate matrices based on the current animation position.
            Matrix headRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(HeadRotation);
            Matrix headScale = Matrix.CreateScale(HeadScale);
            Matrix bodyRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(BodyRotation);

            // Apply matrices to the relevant bones.
            headBone.Transform = headScale * headRotation * headTransform;
            bodyBone.Transform = bodyRotation * bodyTransform;

            // Look up combined bone matrices for the entire model.
            bodyModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(boneTransforms);

            // Draw the model.
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in bodyModel.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.World = boneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;

                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }

        public float HeadRotation { get; set; }

        public float HeadScale { get; set; }

        public float BodyRotation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron Anodide very much. Can you share me sample code about one person moving. I know rotation and scale one model, but I don't know change its shape such as one person moving or stand up and sit down. Design model file(.fbx) is very hard too!

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I believe a person moving would be the same thing, just using a Translation matrix to adjust the position of the model on the x/y/z axis... if you think about it, what part of a person moving, standing or sitting isn't a product of the transforms Rotation, Sclae and Translation?

Comment: I'm trying to create elastic springs!!

Comment: as for the .fbx - i don't think you're supposed to be able to do anything with that - i think it's a way that tools like Blender and Cinema 4D can export models you create in a way that the XNA framework can read... i find it to be a pretty smooth experience so far

Comment: again, this is just a beginner taking a guess, but since there's really no magic involved and it's all just number crunching vertecies, I think you have to go to the level of thinking of a spring as a huge collection of polygons - maybe a bunch of "disc primitives"... i think i'm at the end of my usefulness here - like i said i'm a beginner too